# Link to new HTML page with button - Typescript

Tags: html, typescript, navigation

how to refer to a new HTML page in Typescript? I would like that when you click on the button on the home page, the other page opens (no separate window, just overwrites the home page).

I tried that but it just adds the content of the new page at the bottom and I don't want that:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('home');
this.router.navigate(['/','home']);
```

Comment: Can you add the angular router you have? In the normal cases all routes will be rendered where you have declared your angular router-outlet.

Comment: I can add multiple routes but it is only added and not overwritten. The path then looks like this: http://localhost:4200/home

PS: I'm not a pro in Angular

Answer (score 0):

please try this one <button [routeLink]="['/location']"> Location .

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either. The content of the other HTML page is only added below. Maybe I created the routes wrong?
import {LandingpageComponent} from "./landingpage/landingpage.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'landingpage', component: LandingpageComponent}];

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Anna,

If I understood you right.)

I guess it might be something with router-outlet.

Maybe, in your html file you're adding some components first, and than router-outlet. That's why you see components and then the content below you want to render.

For example in your root app.component.html if you'll add such structure:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-about></app-about>
<router-outlet></router-outlet> // Shows your routing component
```

And in your routing paths:

```
{path: 'home', component: HomeComponent} // <router-outlet> by the path 'home' shows exactly the HomeComponent.
```

You will see in the browser: HeaderComponent, AboutComponent and HomeComponent(and everything what contains header, about and home.component.html).

If you want owerwrite page by HomeComponent, from your app.components.html you need to delete tags:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-about></app-about>.
```